# UPDATE only specific fields of database table from internal table

Tags: abap, opensql

I need to update two fields called F1 and F2 within database table called **ANLZ**.

Table **ANLA** has a field called ACTIVE that states, whether the fields in **ANLZ** can be updated.

Key for connecting both tables is field **ANLN1**

Data declaration:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF TY_ANLZ,
   ANLN1 TYPE ANLZ-ANLN1,
   ACTIVE TYPE ANLA-ACTIVE,
   F1 TYPE ANLZ-F1,
   F2 TYPE ANLZ-F2,
  END OF TY_ANLZ.

DATA LT_ANLZ TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF TY_ANLZ.
```

First, I do inner join that gives me only records that are active in ANLA and corresponding fields F1, F2 from ANLZ.

```
SELECT F1, F2, ANLA~ACTIVE, ANLA~ANLN1 FROM ANLZ AS ANLZ
   INNER JOIN ANLA AS ANLA
   ON ANLA~ANLN1 EQ ANLZ~ANLN1
   WHERE ANLA~ACTIVE EQ 'Y'
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @lt_anlz.
```

Now I need to access ANLZ and update it with the filtered ANLZ-F1 and ANLZ-F2 using static value(e.g. ****), how do I do that please? What is the most sufficient way?

I was thinking, but I'm not sure if the usage of loop is good with regards to performance(tens thousands of records).

```
LOOP AT lt_anlz ASSIGNING <fs_anlz>.
   UPDATE anlz SET F1 = <fs_anlz>-F1,
                   F2 = <fs_anlz>-F2
                   WHERE ANLN1 = <fs_anlz>-ANLN1.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Note that SAP highly recommends to not update standard fields directly, you should use official API instead so that database consistency is ensured.

Comment: Second Sandra point. Especially this is true for asset tables ANLZ, ANLA, ANLN, etc. Soon you will get into trouble

Comment: Sandra, may I ask what do you mean by the official API? Any reference please?

Comment: I assume @SandraRossi is talking about the transaction code BAPI which is a library of function modules especially designed for use in customer code to read and change data from SAP modules. The `BAPI*` function modules are guaranteed by SAP to not change when upgrading the system and do a lot of "behind the scenes" stuff that needs to happen when changing data. Like checking permissions, doing substitutions and validations, executing events and writing change documents.

Comment: I'm talking about any standard means to update data programatically. You have BAPIs, Web Services, Batch Input, SAP GUI Scripting, Direct Input, LSMW, LT, anything that is documented in SAP ERP documentation, SAP Support, etc. There's a lot to search, I don't have time to do it for you ;-) NB: SAP support may not assist you in case you tweaked the software, like changing the data leading to inconsistencies.

Comment: @SandraRossi "The BAPI* function modules are guaranteed by SAP to not change when upgrading the system". This is only true for the released BAPIs to be strict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulk writing the table with one [`UPDATE FROM @itab`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapupdate_source.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_3@3@) will likely be faster than creating one single transaction for each record (assuming anln1 is the primary key):

```
UPDATE anlz FROM TABLE @lt_anlz.
```

Comment: typo: `UPDATE anlz FROM TABLE @lt_anlz.` Note that the ABAP Database Interface may split it into several single UPDATE statements, so it's not always faster.

Comment: What I'd want to update only specific fields with this ``FROM TABLE`` ? In the example above I specify what I want to update(meaning only F1 and F2), does this kind of update know what needs to be updated? And yes, ANLN1 is the primary key.

Comment: @smoothlikebutter it'll update all non-primary key fields that are part of the table line.

Answer (score 3):

From ABAP release 7.55 you can declare indicator structures along with the statement TYPES. The see relevant documentation [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abaptypes_indicators.htm).

> The addition INDICATORS of the UPDATE FROM clause can be used to specify set indicators for a work area or an internal table. The purpose of set indicators is to indicate columns to be changed. UPDATE FROM without indicators overwrites all fields of a row but when set indicators are used, only the indicated fields are updated. The addition can be specified only after UPDATE FROM for structured work areas wa or internal tables itab with a structured row type. The source work area or internal table must have a structure set_ind as last field with the same number of components as the DDIC database table to be updated, and each component serves as set indicator for one row. There is a static variant and a dynamic variant.

The example is as follows:

```
INSERT demo_update FROM TABLE @(
    VALUE #( ( id = 'A' col1 = '1' col2 = '10'   col3 = '100')
             ( id = 'B' col1 = '2' col2 = '20'   col3 = '200')
             ( id = 'C' col1 = '3' col2 = '30'   col3 = '300')
             ( id = 'D' col1 = '4' col2 = '40'   col3 = '400')
             ( id = 'E' col1 = '5' col2 = '50'   col3 = '500')
             ( id = 'F' col1 = '6' col2 = '60'   col3 = '600') ) ).

TYPES ind_wa TYPE demo_update WITH INDICATORS col_ind
             TYPE abap_bool.
DATA ind_tab TYPE TABLE OF ind_wa.

ind_tab = VALUE #(
       ( id = 'D' col4 = 4000 col_ind-col4 = abap_true )
       ( id = 'E' col4 = 5000 col_ind-col4 = abap_true )
       ( id = 'F' col4 = 6000 col_ind-col4 = abap_true ) ).

UPDATE demo_update FROM TABLE @ind_tab
                   INDICATORS SET STRUCTURE col_ind.

* See first result

UPDATE demo_update FROM TABLE @ind_tab.

* See second result
```

### First result with indicators used

| Client | ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | A | 1 | 10 | 100 | 0 |
| 000 | B | 2 | 20 | 200 | 0 |
| 000 | C | 3 | 30 | 300 | 0 |
| 000 | D | 4 | 40 | 400 | 4000 |
| 000 | E | 5 | 50 | 500 | 5000 |
| 000 | F | 6 | 60 | 600 | 6000 |

### Second result without indicators

Note how the values in column `col1`, `col2` and `col4` are set to the initial value (same value as in the internal table).

| Client | ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | A | 1 | 10 | 100 | 0 |
| 000 | B | 2 | 20 | 200 | 0 |
| 000 | C | 3 | 30 | 300 | 0 |
| 000 | D | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4000 |
| 000 | E | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5000 |
| 000 | F | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6000 |